# Undefined index: username in [...]\joomla\user\authentication.php on line 321

Tags: php, joomla, authentication

I'm a newbie to Joomla and want to understand how Joomla! API works.

I have this piece of code in an external file that connects to another joomla site call APITEST

Basically, I have already created a user that has username: `demo` and password `demo12`. I want to use the `login()` method from `JApplication` class.

```
<?php
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__).DS."../apitest/");

require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );
require_once( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'libraries' . DS . 'joomla' . DS . 'factory.php' );

$user = JFactory::getApplication('site');

$credential = array('demo', 'demo12');
$remember = array(true);

print_r($user->login($credential, $remember));

?>
```

However it gives me this error message:

```
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\libraries\joomla\user\authentication.php on line 321

Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\libraries\joomla\user\authentication.php on line 326

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\apitest\libraries\joomla\user\authentication.php on line 331
```

I expect the result to return True. How can I do so? Thanks.

Comment: show code of `authentication.php`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joomla is looking for the username and password in an associative array, not a numerical keyed array, which is what you have.

Change to:

```
$credential = array('username' => 'demo', 'password' => 'demo12');
```

Comment: Thanks! They should have written it in their doc.

Comment: on line 1 or 320 add $index = NULL;